# How to display kendo grid pager info when toolbar is present?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a kendo grid inside of a kendo splitter in ASP.Net MVC. My problem is the pager info (i.e. "1 of 20 items") is not displayed on load. If the splitter is moved or a button inside of the splitter is pressed the grid resizes and the pager is displayed correctly. This issue seems to only be present when the grid has a toolbar.

I have tried using the dataBound event to resize the grid elements, but the pager div is not computed yet. I also tried applying a flex box to the pager wrapper and that did not change anything.

I replicated the issue in this dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/URIbinEY/12. The issue appears when in fullscreen mode on a 1920x1080 monitor.

The expected result should show the pager info on load and the grid should fill 100% of the splitter pane.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought I wasn't seeing the issue you described, but then I noticed that the "1-20 of 91 items" text wasn't displaying on initial load.

I referred to [this telerik doc](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Layout/resize-grid-when-the-window-is-resized) and noticed they were setting the size option on the splitter. 
So, I tried adding the size option to the grid pane, and believe it worked (if I was seeing the same wrong behavior you were describing).

Try it out: http://dojo.telerik.com/URIbinEY/13

Comment: Kendo draws the pager correctly if the size is around 400px. 500px did not work. Since the website I am working with is supposed to be dynamic, I changed it to 30% and the issue persisted in full screen.